# Application Map for Application Insights WIth Serilog not Working

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

My original connection with A.I. would produce the correct maps(and live Metrics). Once I linked SeriLog  I am getting the proper AI logs but the Application Map (also the live metrics) are not working. I haven't found any articles that mention if this is the expected outcome or if I've made a mistake in my config. is there any documentation or anything that discusses this issue?

Comment: please share us with your code and config.

Answer (score 3):

Application Map depends on [Dependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/auto-collect-dependencies) telemetry (e.g. http requests) to be logged in Application Insights. With [Serilog sink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/blob/master/README.md), log is sent only as either Trace, Event or Exception. So, if you want the automatic dependency and requests telemetry, I would suggest to have that integration code at startup and leave the Serilog only for application level custom logs.

For example, an asp.net core application, AI integration would be like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core). (there are reference for other type of applications also)

[image]